# Dynamically Filling a Data Grid using a collection of values with row+column coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have an observable collection that has three fields:

Cell Value, Column Index, Row Index

(Edit: Each object of the list has these three fields)

Is there a way I can bind this observable collection to a Data Grid using the column index and row index to specify the location of each cell? The observable collection is in column order (first object is [row 1, col 1], second object is [row 1, col 2] etc.) if that helps.

It's important that it follows the MVVM pattern which is causing me the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the `UniformGrid`. You can bind to `Rows` and `Columns` to tell it your dimensions (properties of your view model). Then you build around an `ItemsControl` and feed in your data via `ItemsSource`. The rest is about styling (how you want to look like your table). The following XAML might give you a starting Point. `MyList` here is simply a list of `int`for testing.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Rows}" Columns="{Binding Columns}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however in this case I need to be able to select cells and read data like you can do with a DataGrid. It appears that UniformGrid just allows me to print out the cell values.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks at this schema. Lets say i have object Person that have two properties: FirstName and LastName. Now I have an collection of Person.

Now If you have dataGrid, your columns will be populated according to your object's properties(In this example firstName and lastName), and for each item in our collections we will have new Row.
So this is illustration of this dataGrid:

```
___ | FirstName | LastName

1    FirstItem   LastFirstItem
2    SecondItem  LastSecondItem
```